# Swap Product Image with Selected Thumbnail Image

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a product show case with some thumbnail image below. Click on the thumbnail image the product image will able to swap to the selected image with the same url. May I know how I am able to write the script for this function?

https://jsfiddle.net/g989p9a3/9/

```
$('.magnify .col').onClick(function(){        
  $(".magnify .col").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  var imgURL = $(this).find('img').attr("src");    
  $('.magnify.small').find('img').attr("src", imgURL);    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if you still haven't figured this one out but:

```
$('.magnify .col').click(function(){        
    $(".magnify .col").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var imgURL = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
    var temp = $('.magnify .small').attr("src");
    $('.magnify .small').attr("src", imgURL);
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', temp);
});
```

all you had to change was

`.onClick` to `.click` (or `.on('click')`) and

`$('.magnify.small').find('img')` to `$('.magnify.small')`, since `$('.magnify.small')` is already the image.

also you said something about swapping the images, not just showing the thumbnail you click because this way you would end up losing one of the three, so I added:

```
var temp = $('.magnify .small').attr("src");
$(this).find('img').attr('src', temp);
```

hope it helps

```js
$('.magnify .col').click(function(){        
    $(".magnify .col").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var imgURL = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
    var temp = $('.magnify .small').attr("src");
    $('.magnify .small').attr("src", imgURL);
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', temp);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
img.small {
  width: 200px;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 magnify">
  <div class="large"></div>
  <img src="http://www.sonatamusicart.com.my/3rd_mocksite/img/retail/guitar/guitar.jpg" class="img-fluid small">
  <div class="row remove-margin">
    <a href="#" class="col">
      <img src="http://www.sonatamusicart.com.my/3rd_mocksite/img/retail/guitar/guitar-brown.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="col">
      <img src="http://www.sonatamusicart.com.my/3rd_mocksite/img/retail/guitar/guitar-dark-brown.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="col">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. Also I included jQuery. Check out the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/g989p9a3/17/

```
$('.magnify .col').on('click', function() {
    $(".magnify .col").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var imgURL = $(this).find('img').prop("src");
    $('.magnify .small').prop("src", imgURL);
});
```